# Can ssh onto server using PuTTY, but not ssh from terminal

Tags: command-line, server, ssh

I have a very simple Ubuntu server with a couple of git repos on it, nothing special.

At home I used a Windows PC, and use the [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) program to interact with the server. At work however I have a Mac, and using ssh to login to the server I am getting a timeout message each time.

I know the server is up and running, because I am able to access it via a built in console function on my hosting website (Digital Ocean).

Example:

```
MacBook-Pro: documents jmr$ ssh jmr@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
ssh: connect to host XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX port 22: Operation timed out
```

I've searched around quite a bit for solutions to this specific issue but have yet to find anything that addresses this. Any help is appreciated, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your port is open at work! Some companies block certain ports, and port 22 would be a great first candidate!

You can test that with telnet for example:

```
telnet you.rse.rve.rip 22
```

You could also use **portquiz.net** :

```
$telnet portquiz.net 22
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4
```

If your request is timing out too than your port is most probably being blocked.

Comment: Doing that also resulted in a timeout... I think I should talk to someone here at work to determine if that is what is happening.

Comment: You can also use portquiz.net, I'll edit the answer to reflect that.

Comment: What am I looking for exactly with portquiz? My output looked like this:

`telnet portquiz.net 22
Trying IP ADDRESS WHICH ISNT MINE BUT IM UNSURE IF ITS SENSITIVE SO IM REMOVING IT...
Connected to portquiz.net.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4`

Comment: Then it's not a port issue ;) At least not if you try to reach portquiz.net

Comment: Can you ping your server from work?

Comment: Pinging works fine, no packet loss on over 100+ attempts

Comment: Hmm, can you limit access to SSH to only certain IPs in DigitalOceans backend?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13667/discussion-between-jmrboosties-and-mistrfu)